# How to set range for an editText preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have an editText preference in my Settings Activity.
I want to get a number from 0-99 from the user.
How can i do that?

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="90"
    android:key="key_a"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:title="@string/pref_title"/>
```

Using this code i have restricted the input to numbers,but i want to further restrict the user from entering more than 2 digits.

If restriction is not possible,any validation method to check if the entered input is <= 99 and if the entered input is invalid, i would like to change the value to its previously saved value.

Comment: if you want to limit the number for two digits then simply use android:maxLength="2"

Answer (score 1):

Adding `android:maxLength="2"` solved it.  Thanks *@Suraj Nair*